# Magento + HTTP/2, anyone noticed any issues?

Tags: https, http-request

Since Apache now properly supports HTTP/2, have any of you already tried running it and noticed any improvements and/or issues for Magento 1.9.x.?

Comment: Although the question is too broad It's quite interesting. I wouldn't mind keeping it open to see if anyone has an answer